# Improve Powershell Get-WinEvent Script Performance

Tags: powershell

The following script takes 5-10 minutes per server to return the events. I am currently only querying the last 7 days of events.  The servers are all Windows Server 2012 R2 servers.  Is there a better way to write this that might improve its performance?  The highest summarized count for events so far has been 24,509 (sum of all event counts).  It seems like this shouldn't take over 5 minutes but maybe I'm expecting too much?

For reference:

```
$eventlogs = 'application, system'
$eventlevels = '1','2','3'
$startdate = get-date
$enddate = [DateTime]::Today.AddDays(-7)

Get-WinEvent -ComputerName $server -FilterHashTable @{LogName=$eventLogs; Level=$eventLevels; StartTime=$startDate; EndTime=$endDate} -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue `
| Group-Object LogName, ProviderName, ID, {$_LevelDisplayName}, Count `
| Select-Object @{N="Log"; E={$_.Group[0].LogName}}, `
@{N="Provider"; E={$_.Group[0].ProviderName}}, `
@{N="Error ID"; E={$_.Group[0].ID}}, `
@{N="Type"; E={$_.Group[0].LevelDisplayName}}, `
count, `
@{N="Message"; E={$_.Group[0].Message.Replace("`r",' ').Replace("`n",' ')}} `
| Sort-Object  "Type" `
| Export-Csv -notypeinformation -Path $file
```

Comment: Read this: http://blogs.technet.com/b/heyscriptingguy/archive/2011/03/08/how-to-improve-the-performance-of-a-powershell-event-log-query.aspx

Comment: Calculated properties is huge time drain. Hell, using the pipeline at all isn't fast. I'd suggest just grabbing all of the events you need into a variable and then picking out what you want with the .foreach() method if you're using PowerShell v4+.